# Check data an then submit on submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
$('.survey-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var n_elements = 0
  var form_submitted = $(this).serializeArray();
  n_elements = $('.form-group.form-widget').length;
  var answered = checkAllnswered(form_submitted, n_elements);

  if (answered)
    // then submit
  else
    // message
});
```

If I use:

```
if (answered)
  $(this).submit
```

I get a 'too much recursion' error. How I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it's `$(this).submit()` - note the trailing `()` to call the function, although that's not the cause of your problem.

To submit the form without triggering the jQuery `submit` event handler call `submit()` on the Element object, not the jQuery object:

```
if (answered)
  this.submit();
```